# How to add plugins for ios in phonegap?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am new to phonegap.

Using phonegap app I have created new project.

[image]

Now I like to use this project in xcode (7.2.1) is it possible?

What is the best way to develop app in phonegap for various plugin ,I was googled and heard about coredova but can't understand exact needed .

Comment: You mean you want to install any plugin after created project right ?

Comment: yes @jaydroider......

Comment: Have you created project with cordova ? or You directly need to add plugin for created project ?

Comment: i want to directly plugin my created project

Comment: @jaydroider got it ?

Comment: Try with my Answer. Let me know if you have any doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For IOS Try this to add any new Plugin.**

**Go to your `Created Project Directory` in `Mac CLI`.**

`Then do this.`

`If you haven't added IOS Platform then run below command`.

```
cordova platform add ios
```

`Then build your whole project with below command.`

```
cordova prepare ios
```

`Then to add plugin run below command.`

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git
```

**Here take whatever plugin you want to install.**

Make sure you connected with internet while installing plugin.

Comment: i need to install cordova for that ?

Comment: If you have created project with `Cordova Create` and if it's created then not needful. Because you have told that you have already created project with cordova. so It will work.

Comment: i have created new project bro but i didn't installed it .only phonegap application i have ,(or) coredova is inbuild?

Comment: Brother try with this command `create Firstapp com.firstapp.app First app` if it's show you cordova project created then you don't need to.

Comment: If it will show error then you need to install cordova.

Comment: Try installing cordova brother and then check.

Comment: @KishoreKumar Bro have you installed cordova ? Check this link if not done https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide/cli/

Comment: @KishoreKumar Bro install cordova from link i have given in above comment in `Mac CLI` and try all the steps i have suggested.

Comment: @KishoreKumar Upvote it also if it is helpful to you bro thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> Now I like to use this project in xCode (7.2.1) is it possible?*

Yes it is possible, [Read this article](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/archive/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-xcode-for-ios.html)

> What is the best way to develop app in phonegap for various plugin

I am assuming you are asking how to add different plugins?

1. Create your APP with the PhoneGap Interface (You already did)
2. Go to the `www` folder where you stored the PG build files and look for your config.xml, then you will see a section where a few plugins already exists. You can add additional ones by just simply copying and pasting the below XML syntax (Battery Status Plugin), example:

   `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" spec="1.1.0" source="pgb" />`

Reference this article for a comprehensive list of PhoneGap's plugins: 
https://build.phonegap.com/plugins

Alternatively, you can add them through the Command Line interface (See the first answer to your question)

Comment: @ander3wap  i read the article but in the article they provided link to download coredova but nothing is there in link bro

Comment: You already have PhoneGap installed (Your screenshot) - so skip that step.

Comment: @andre3wrap there is no coredova framework in xcode ,so i think it is impossible to plugin